# How to use awk to cut text file

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to use awk to cut a long text that I found from a website I want. I will save the txt from the part of the text that starts with xxx to the part that ends with xxx in a file

Comment: Hi, welcome to unix.SE. Please provide an example of text you want to filter. Using `sed` and `awk` is very specific to the job at hand. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also helpful would be to show what you have tried, and explain how it did not work as expected or intended.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is extremely vague and lacks a clear input example, AWK can help us make a generalized solution based on the few details you indicated.

The following code should work if there are up to two instances of xxx in your text and even if there are no line breaks in it. Awk is a line-oriented language, and therefore we have to work around the lines being evaluated separately. Using other methods like sed might be better suited for this job using a regex expression.

```
BEGIN{printer="false"}
printer=="true" && $0 !~ /xxx/ {print $0}
printer=="false" && $0 ~ /xxx/  {printer="true"; split($0,a,"xxx"); print a[2]; next}
printer=="true" && $0 ~ /xxx/ {split($0,b,"xxx"); print b[1]; printer="false"; exit}
```

test a:

```
xxxLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
eu fugiat nulla pariatur.xxx Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

test b:

```
xxxLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.xxx Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Comment: Feel free to modify your question so others that feel inclined to answer see it. The example should be easy to extend to your use case.